# How to set yscale to log of log?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

In pyplot there is an option to set yscale like this

`ax.set_yscale('log')`

but is there any work around to plot on 2nd degree log on y axis maybe something like this

`ax.set_yscale('loglog')`

PS: To clear confusion, the question is not how to transform and plot which is obviously trivial. The question is to plot keeping labels unaffected as it is with `ax.set_yscale('log')`

Comment: Of course you could take the log of your and plot it is a log-scale. Or take the log twice and plot it on a normal scale

Comment: Avoid complications and simply use something like `plt.plot(x,np.log10(np.log10(y)))`

Comment: @Bazingaa Can you give the full code on how to print values along y axis in such case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a small working code for you with the double log

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(10)
y = 10**np.arange(1, 11)
plt.plot(x,np.log10(np.log10(y)), '-kx')
plt.yticks(np.log10(np.log10(y)), y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: You didn't get my point. Y axis labeling are going for a toss. say for example here the Y axis lables was not 1.2, it was 1000000000000000. I said can you give code to remap that back?

Comment: What you exactly want is unclear to me, sorry. Provide a desired input/output in your question. Even a hand drawn plot uploaded as an image in your question would work. Or simply provide some sample input/output as text.

Comment: Y axis labels should be y values ie (10, 100,   ..., 1000000000000000) not (0.2,0.3....1.2) . If you look at your plot properly you will notice you have labeled (0.2,0.3....1.2). With `ax.set_yscale('log')` approach labels don't get affected as you are not changing Y but the just compressing the vertical view but with your approach the labels are getting affected as you are creating a new Y. I dont know how more I can explain. Please look at your plot more carefully you will notice.

Comment: The question was not how to transform and plot which is obviously trivial. The question was to plot keeping labels unaffected as it is with `ax.set_yscale('log')`

Comment: @ishandutta2007: Ok, got it. Check my edited plot/answer and see if that works