# How can I render a scatter plot in Python with a "double-log" axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

[image]

This plot is from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birch_and_Swinnerton-Dyer_conjecture), and the legend reads:

> The X-axis is in log(log) scale -X is drawn at distance proportional to
> log(log(X)) from 0- and the Y-axis is in a logarithmic scale

How can it be reproduced in python?

The option:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.xscale('log')
ax.scatter(p, mult, facecolor='blue', marker='.', s=10)
plt.show()
```

is not the same:

[image]

Comment: There is an [identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67221265/matplotlib-loglogx-scale) on StackOverflow from 3 years ago without any answers. Maybe the links in the comments can help you. It seems there is no prebuild way to do this and one has to define a [custom scale class](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/scales/custom_scale.html)

Comment: Related, but maybe not exactly what you want: [How to set yscale to log of log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53568460/how-to-set-yscale-to-log-of-log).

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ticks = [np.log(np.log(10**i)) for i in range(1,7)]
ax.set_xticks(ticks)

labels = [r'$10^ %s$' % k for k in range(1,7)]
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Using 10,000 primes and sage math, the reproduction is immediate:
[image]